# Why does createNewFile() fail to create a file?

Tags: java

Following code fails and I'm at a complete loss.

```
File newFile = new File ("C:/users/user/desktop/fruit" + "apple" + ".csv");

if (!newFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("file not found");
    if (newFile.createNewFile()) {
        System.out.println("file created");
    } else {
        System.out.println("file DOESN'T exist");
    }
}
FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter(newFile);
```

file not found
file DOESN'T exist

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\users\user\desktop\fruit\apple.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:292)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:185)
    at java.base/java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:96)
    at dataformatting/dataFormatting.formatting.main(formatting.java:47)
```

Comment: Clearly this isn't the real code, as the filenames don't match. However, you should get rid of the entire `if` block and let `new FileWriter()` throw an exception. That will save you two directory searches and a file creation and a deletion. `new FileWriter()` is all you need. Don't write pointless code. What you *do* need however is to ensure that the *directory* exists, with `newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()`.

Comment: So there's a file called "C:/users/user/desktop/fruitapple.csv" that you can see if you list the directory contents?

Answer (score 5):

You are making a file called `fruitapple.csv` on your desktop and trying to open a file called `apple.csv` in a folder called `fruit` on your `desktop`...

Comment: Not with the code he posted.

Comment: @user207421 Check the error...

Comment: I can see the error, and I can also see that the filename in the code doesn't match the error, and I can also see that he is using the same `File` for both `createNewFile()` and `new FileWriter()`, which means that what you said in your answer about two different filenames isn't correct. The actual error is almost certainly that the parent directory doesn't exist.